# while loop to break after list reaches certain length

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm sure this is answered somewhere, but my searches have come up empty.

I want to fill a list until it reaches a certain length, I'm not sure why this doesn't work:

```
test = []
while len(test) < 5:
    for i in range(10):
        test.append(i)  # I would think this would exit the while loop once i==4 is appended, but it doesn't
len(test)

[out]: 10
```

The real code has a bunch of `ifelse` statements in the while loop that will add to list `test`, and I'd rather not evaluate the length of the list at the end of each conditional statement to cause a `break` or something similar.

Comment: The `while` loop only checks the condition after the stuff inside the while loop finished and it loops. Here the entire `for` loop runs before the length is checked.

Comment: The `while` condition is tested every time the loop repeats. The list goes from length 0 to 10 in one iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation will allow you to make a list of the limit using the `range()` function

See more about the range function and its arguments [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

```py
limit = 5
your_list = []
for x in range(0,limit):
   your_list.append(x)
```

Comment: the `0` here is kind of redundant as it will start from that, and as shown in my answer its much easier to just use `list(range(limit))`

Comment: Yeah the `0` is redundant for this example, but I think it's important to learn that it is possible for the `range()` function to have a lower limit.

Comment: Oh yeah sure. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Answer (score -1):

So in your original code, you run that for loop inside the loop, it only checks at the end so it goes through code (adds 10 items) and then `breaks`

here would be a proper way to do that

```
test = []
while len(test) < 5:
    test.append(1)

print(len(test))
```

```
5
```

and if you want a list of everything in that range just do the following:

```
list(range(10))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the range of your `for`-loop to make sure it doesn't go over the limit of the `while`-loop:

```py
while_loop_max = 5
for_loop_max = 10
test = []
while len(test) < while_loop_max:
  for i in range(min(for_loop_max, while_loop_max - len(test))):
    test.append(i)
print(len(test), test)
# 5 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

while_loop_max = 15
for_loop_max = 10
test = []
while len(test) < while_loop_max:
  for i in range(min(for_loop_max, while_loop_max - len(test))):
    test.append(i)
print(len(test), test)
# 15 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```